# DNS redirect based on local or remote network connection

Tags: apache, dns, debian, iptables, openvpn

I have a domain name mysite.com pointed to my dedicated server (debian 7).
Authenticated users will be behind OpenVPN with local addresses and masquerading.

What I want to do is send unauthenticated users to the server's remote ip and authenticated users to the local ip. To make things even more interesting, I have a reverse proxy setup to send a sub domain to a different port.

So far I have looked at iptables prerouting, and apache2 proxy.

The basic idea is if the user can reach 10.8.0.1 the domain mysite.com should resolve to 10.8.0.1 otherwise is should resolve to the remote ip. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openVPN allows you to specify a DNS server along with the VPN-IP address. if you control this DNS-server, you can easily create an ACL that will return `10.8.0.1` for queries originating from the VPN network, and the public IP address when the queries come from outside of this network.

in the openVPN config, you would add something like the following (assuming your DNS-server has the IP `10.8.0.53`)

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.53"
```

how to configure your DNS-server will obviously depend on the actual server you are using (which you didn't mention).
in `bind9` it would look similar to the following:

```
acl authenticated { 10.8.0.0/24; };

view "authenticated" {
   match-clients { authenticated; };
   zone "mysite.com" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/db.authenticated";
   };
};
view "anonymous" {
   match-clients { any; }
   zone "mysite.com" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/db.anonymous";
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply! I actually didn't want to host my own DNS server for this but it seems it may be the only way to go. GoDaddy is hosting my domain and as such I do not have much control. I am pushing google's public dns wigth OpenVPN currently but I will look into this.

Comment: you could setup a DNS-server *only* for authenticated hosts (skip the 'anonymous' view) that overrides the GoDaddy resolver.

Comment: Took some time to learn DNS and Bind but got it setup and working using the above method. Thanks!